# TCP secured connection - only via my client

Tags: security, tcp, network-programming

so I have this TCP connections between my server and client, and anyone can connect to my server. But I want to make sure that the client is really using MY client application and not just faking messages from a fake TCP client. What would be the ways to do that, check that the connection really is from my game client?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
If I'm gonna use TLS, can I solve that problem?

Comment: Impossible to do with 100% reliability. If it's worth someone's time to do so, they'll bypass any check you could think to do. Whatever solution you end up with, just make it be more expensive to do than whatever it is you're using the connection for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will probably not be a complete solution to your problem, since whatever you do, the other party might always take your program, run it in a monitored environment, manipulate the runtime data and let it use its "secure" network protocol. Since the client application is in uncontrollable hands, you can never be sure that it is your own program.

Baby example: My application runs your application and plays back the data to your server, and forwards your response back to the application. How can you tell?

That said, it might be a very promising "99%" approach to use SSL and hardcode the client's private key into the application -- with some trickery you can try and make it hard to find (e.g. see how Skype does it). If you then also build integrity checks into your program that figure out whether anyone is manipulating the memory or debugging into your program, you can try and make it a bit harder for a potential adversary. (But note that you will always *have* to ship the private key with your application, so it isn't really safe from discovery.)

Comment: @user: [Here, check it out](http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-europe-06/bh-eu-06-biondi/bh-eu-06-biondi-up.pdf) -- I'm sure if you put an extra afternoon in, you can rig up something like that for your client ;-)

Comment: I don't understand. If I'm gonna use TLS, is that gonna solve my problem?

Comment: @Eli: As I said, your problem *has* no complete solution. But using TLS (or rather SSL?) allows you to do some PKI-based authentication which is a reasonably good start.

Comment: Hmmm, OK.. But is it right? -> Logging via SSL. After login, the client starts sending and getting TCP messages from the server using a key that they agreed in SSL message.

Comment: You should read up some basics about security and cryptography. Try [Schneier's book](http://www.schneier.com/book-ce.html) for an extremely clean exposition. The crux is the *authentication* part, by which you verify that the client app holds a private key that (in principle) only you could have given it. The encryption afterwards is optional, you could go for 0-bit encryption if eavesdropping isn't a problem.

Comment: I will. But in the time, I need to start with something. Do you have a better idea that I can use?

Comment: I think SSL is reasonably straight-forward to use, you just have to know what you want. Armed with the understanding of the cryptographic ideas, using SSL in your program shouldn't be terribly hard at all.

Comment: Look, I know it sounds awful, but I have to release my game. I'm still not sure about the secuirty, but I need to start with a good thing. Right now, I don't have a time to read a book like that and understand it - my English is not good. So in my situation, what do you think would be the best way to try ensuring the client?

Comment: First off, this really shouldn't be a major obstacle, since you should never see the effect of this extra layer in most of your code, so you can just keep programming the rest of your game. Ask someone who knows about SSL and they can probably write the session wrapper for you in an hour or so. Or post a question on the "Programmers" sister site -- or even here on SO, if you show us your existing networking code and ask "how to I wrap this in an authenticated SSL connection" or something.

Answer (score 1):

Others have suggested useful answers to your question, but I'm going to suggest another approach. Re-examine your requirements.

Ask yourself *why* you want to know the identity of the client program. Is it so that you can trust your client program more than you trust 3rd-party client programs?

If you need to trust the identity or integrity of software that you have already shipped to your customers, I claim your security model is broken. Once the software runs on a client's PC, you should assume it is evil, even if you originally wrote it.

Any status, any command, any data whatsoever that comes from the network must be checked before it is relied upon.

Comment: How can I do that? The client is an iOS device. I thought that checking the client would be the best way, since the only thing can happen is me to lose money - if the player could break into my system, he can add himself items that costs money, and I don't want that to happen. Maybe 1 or 2 is OK, but if they will share the crack into the internet, I will lose a lot of money.

Answer (score 0):

My default response is to use a challenge/response authentication.

After connection, send a random number from the server to the client
The client then computes, using a hash/key/.... a response message and returns that to the server

If the response matches the servers computation, your chances of authenticity are better.  Note though that a reverse engineer of your client will leave this method open to fraud.

Comment: Also note that this is subject to man-in-the-middle attacks. The attacker lets that part of the protocol run the completion, and then starts injecting his own commands into the now-trusted connection.

Comment: Absolutely. MitM is one of many potential pitfalls.  If the OP wants SECURITY as opposed to security, I feel his studies will be far deeper than this query.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a public/private key pair in order to verify that you are who you say you are.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA#Signing_messages

Comment: And to authenticate on the server, the client needs to sign the message using it's private key. The problem of storing the private key in the way that the user of the application is not able to access it is not solved on general-purpose systems.

Comment: Can't I store it in the code..? iOS application is the client - I don't think it's really possible to access the code . .

Comment: It's not possible to access your source code, but it is certainly possible to access a key contained in the client. iOS devices can be jail broken, and that means that anything you hard code in your app can be read by a third party.

Comment: Hard code - what is that means? You wanna tell me that a jailbroken user can access all of my codes?

Comment: It means that you have to embed the key in your program. When someone downloads your program, they are getting a copy of the key, and if they know what they are doing, they can extract the key and use it make an app which can emulate yours. See Kerrek's answer. There is no way that I am aware of to do this 100% securely.

Comment: OK, so I want to make it as hard as possible. What do you suggest? Here's what I thought ->  Logging via SSL. After login, the client starts sending and getting TCP messages from the server using a key that they agreed in SSL message.